# SQL Table Data Split

Tags: sql, sql-server, outlook

We use a auto function to send email from an outlook mail account to a table in a SQL Server 2014 database.

Table Layout:

```
Column_name Type
Mail_Id uniqueidentifier
Mail_Sender nvarchar
Mail_Sent   datetime
Mail_Received   datetime
Mail_Subject    nvarchar
Mail_Body   nvarchar
```

I'm looking to Split the data in the Mail_body row to the below table and split this in to the correct columns ( See Below)

```
Column_name Type
Client_ID   uniqueidentifier
Client_Name nvarchar
Client_Surname  nvarchar
Email_Address   nvarchar
Phone_Number    nvarchar
DOB nvarchar
Smoker  nvarchar
AOCR    nvarchar
Term    nvarchar
BTTC    nvarchar
Credit_User nvarchar
Insurance_Type  nvarchar
Premium nvarchar
Paid_Commission money
```

Example of Mail_body text string =

```
Sent from my iPhone

Begin forwarded message:


    Product: Life & Critical Illness
    Name: XXXXXX
    Email Address: XXXXXXXX@yahoo.com <mailto:XXXXXXXX@yahoo.com> 
    Phone: 07XXXXXXXX
    Date of Birth: XX/XX/XXXX
    Smoker: Yes
    Amount of cover required: 
    Term: 
    Best Time to Call: Now/ASAP
    Credit User: XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

So if your data is not validated, any solution is going to have a problem (What if the `Name:` line is `Name: Email Address:` (meaning the user entered `Email Address:` as their name)?

Assuming you have some kind of check, `CHARINDEX` is a function you can use.

```
INSERT INTO NewTable 
(FIELDS)
 SELECT 
 ...
 SUBSTRING(Mail_Body,CHARINDEX('Product:', Mail_Body,0),CHARINDEX('Name:', Mail_Body,0)-1),
 ...
FROM OldTable
```

Note that with a long string, it may be more efficient to create a stored procedure that goes through the string keeping track of the previous charindex values, so you don't keep calling the same function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: Possibly however this needs to be ran automatically, i have connected the new table (Data Split) to a Excel db for one of our admins staff to maintain. however the email to db connection will only allow the body to be entered as one text string

Comment: Why couldn't you run this automatically?  Just schedule it in the same job that runs the import, or on a trigger?

Comment: Well this is Server 2014 Express & SQL Server Agent is not part of Express versions

Comment: How are you writing to the DB now?  Couldn't you just use the same method to write to the new table?

Comment: i'm using a plugin that connects from Outlook to SQL via An ODBC connection that will only allow me to pull the whole body of the email. i need the body results to be split into the correct columns on the data split table.

Comment: So you'll need to have a trigger of some kind if you want it to run automatically.  In any case, it will be a variation on what I've posted, how you get it to run automatically is really a preference.  You could make it really hacky, and change your odbc to write to a stage table that then has a trigger that parses the records every write, updates the two tables and truncates itself.  Or you could have a view of the main table that you write to the table with a stored procedure.  Lots of options.  I would build a view of the table first, and go from there.